# Twisted Gelfand pairs (Reference and examples)

Tags: reductive-groups, reference-request, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and let $K$ be a compact group. Let $(\tau, V_\tau)$ be an irreducible representation of $K$.

We consider the space of $Endo_K(\tau)$-valued, compactly supported continuous functions 
$f$ on $G$
with 
$$ f(k_1 g k_2) = \tau(k_1) f(g) \tau(k_2), $$
which is an $*$ algebra under convolution.

What is a good reference for such algebras, especially in the context with reductive group over local fields and the connection to representation theory?

Comment: Since you have no assumption on $K$ (except compactness), I don't see the connection with (twisted) Gelfand pairs... In particular, taking for $K$ the identity subgroup, you get the convolution algebra of compactly supported functions on $G$. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Usually one wants this algebra to be commutative to be a twisted Gelfand pair. 

Comment: Of course, I am mostly interested in some non trivial compact subgroups such as the maximal compact in the case of $GL(N)$. Commutativity doesn't hold in general, I guess?

Comment: My understanding is that the term twisted Gelfand pair is only used when the algebra is commutative. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These Hecke algebras are intensively studied in the field of "type theory" for reductive $p$-adic groups.

You have a nice summary of basic facts *with proofs* in chapter 4 of Bushnell and Kutzko's book "The admissible dual of ${\rm GL}(N)$ via compact open subgroups" (the chapter is entitled "Interlude with Hecke algebras").

You may also read the monography "The Langlands conjecture for ${\rm GL}(2)$", written by Bushnell and Henniart. You'll find there a nice introduction to these algebras.

There are many other references. But it depends on what exactly you're interested in.

Comment: And do you know references for the maximal compact subgroups in Lie groups?
I would be mostly interested how twisted Gelfand pairs are related to Hecke eigenvalues.

Comment: I'm not a specialist of real groups, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately, they only deal with locally profinite groups, instead of discussing special properties of $GL(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

A classical reference for twisted Gelfand pairs is J.R. Stembridge, On Schur's Q-functions and the primitive idempotents of a commutative Hecke algebra, J. Algebr. Comb. 1 (1992) 71–95, but I believe this paper considers only finite groups.

Comment: Compact groups are essentially finite groups;)